# MITM over TLS trust via convergence

Tags: tls, certificate-authority

I see some of the great benefits of (the now old) Moxie's Convergence or CM's Perspective. However, how do they fight the attack of a MITM sat in a common network path of both client and notary on the way to the server? Both the notary and the client will see the same forged certificate, and it will be validated as correct.

Yes, different notaries are in different locations, but what if all of them have to pass through some common network path? (e.g. the Great Wall of China)

Comment: Why would it be any different from the way it works now? The way I understood it was that it was similar to the current structure, but you require n trusted certificates instead of just 1.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald That does not seem to be true, though I am currently unable to find how notaries would verify certificates. It was implied it is automated, simply notaries visiting the site and comparing the certc, assuming it would be impractical to MITM large amount of notaries, though that might be a mistake. https://www.helpnetsecurity.com/2011/09/30/ssl-labs-launches-two-convergence-notaries/

Comment: @PeterHarmann Ah, you are correct, I've definitely misunderstood it. Unfortunately I'm having a hard time finding technical information for it as well... I guess I'll just have to watch the BlackHat video.

Comment: It is seem to me that trust is built on the fact that more than one "trusted" entities (which are geographically distributed) are receiving the exact same certificate, therefore my question of how the technology prevents MITM attacks on shared network paths